# Polynomial Bound on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an old qual problem I can't seem to solve:

Let $p$ be a polynomial with degree $n$ s.t. $|p(z)| \leq 1$ on the closed unit disk. Show $|p(z)| \leq |z|^n$ for $z$ outside the unit disk.

I tried looking at $ z^n p(\frac{1}{z})$ since its holomorphic and has the same norm on the boundary but can't get things to work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we denote $p(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kz^k$, and define (per your suggestion) $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ by
$$f(w):=\begin{cases}w^n p(\frac{1}{w}) & z\neq 0\\ a_n & z=0\end{cases},$$
then indeed $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ (as it's continuous at $z=0$) and for all $w\in S^1$ we have $|f(w)|\leq 1$, implying that $|f|\leq 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$. This, in turn, gives us (for $|z|>1$):
$$|p(z)| = \left|p\left(\frac{1}{1/z}\right)\right| = \left|z^n f(1/z)\right|\leq |z|^n$$